DevExpress TreeList layout not restoring from stream
I have a DevExpress TreeList that is being used on a project I am working on. Some functionality that is being used is to be able to add columns and other edits to the TreeList to then save out the layout to a DB by user and then to restore that layout when the user opens it again.
When adding a column to this specific TreeList and saving out the layout the layout gets saved and stored in the DB as expected however, when trying to restore the layout from the stream it does not bring the saved layout in and instead uses what was setup in the designer. This seems to be an issue with the RestoreLayoutFromStream() method as when I call SaveLayoutToStream() right after this and compare them the value that I restored from and the saved out value are not the same.
I've tried looking into DevExpress issues and their own documentation but am at a loss as the closest issue I can find is talking about the columns not having Name property set on the columns. I have triple checked and that property is being set on all of my columns though. I do also have other TreeLists that I am using that do behave as intended but when looking through differences between the two I can't see anything that stands out to be causing this.
If anyone has any ideas that would be great! I am a little hesitant on sharing code for it right now as the code is my companies and not mine but if needed I can try and make it more generic and share that.
